How to ensure WireGuard traffic is confined to a Linux network namespace without internet access on the host?
I’m trying to configure WireGuard (WG) inside a Linux network namespace (mynamespace) in such a way that all WireGuard traffic is limited to the network namespace and does not affect the host system’s network. However, I’m encountering issues where I am unable to access the internet from within the namespace, even though WireGuard is active.
Here is some relevant information:
Network Namespace Routes:
sudo ip netns exec mynamespace ip route show
default dev wg0 scope link

Network Namespace Interfaces:
sudo ip netns exec mynamespace ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK> mtu 65536 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
4: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/none

WireGuard Configuration inside the Namespace:
sudo ip netns exec mynamespace wg showconf wg0
[Interface]
ListenPort = 44574
FwMark = 0xca6c
PrivateKey = PrivateKey

[Peer]
PublicKey = PublicKey
PresharedKey = PrehashedKey
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0
Endpoint = endpoint

WireGuard Config on server
docker exec wg-easy cat /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf
  

# Note: Do not edit this file directly.
# Your changes will be overwritten!

# Server
[Interface]
PrivateKey = private
Address = 10.8.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820
PreUp = 
PostUp =  iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; 
PreDown = 
PostDown =  iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE; iptables -D INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; 


# Client: test (c8d80092-7212-4d49-be6e-b35af0145a28)
[Peer]
PublicKey = pub key
PresharedKey = pre hashed key
AllowedIPs = 10.8.0.2/32

# Client: [idor (f4c34cf0-2dc8-4a0a-817d-80fed9473d92)
[Peer]
PublicKey = pub key
PresharedKey = prehashed key

Dns resolve config
sudo ip netns exec mynamespace cat /etc/resolv.conf

nameserver 1.1.1.1

Problem:

The route inside the namespace is set to default dev wg0, but I cannot access the internet within the namespace.
I only want WireGuard traffic to happen within the namespace and not affect the host system’s network at all.
Other interfaces (e.g., eth0) on the host should not be accessible from within the namespace.

What I’ve Tried:

I verified the routing table and wg0 is the only default route within the namespace.
I’ve tried manually adding additional routes and adjusting the WireGuard configuration, but nothing seems to make the internet work inside the namespace.

Goal:

I need to ensure that WireGuard traffic stays contained within the namespace and does not route through the host's network interfaces, while also making sure that the namespace can access the internet through WireGuard.

Thanks!

How did you verify that WireGuard is "active"? Does the client show a successful handshake in wg show? How did you create the WireGuard interface? Did you create the wg0 interface inside or outside the namespace?

If the namespace has no Internet access, then WireGuard interfaces created within that interface also have no Internet access – they won't be able to reach any endpoints that the namespace cannot reach.
The wg0 interface must be created outside the namespace, then moved into the namespace so that its 'outer' side retains the Internet access.
ip link set wg0 netns <name_or_pid>

